# Why my profile is missing?

Tags: discussion

I have joined this site two years before, but now i am no more able to continue with my old profile. Please help me to get my profile back. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your profile is missing but you should contact the site using this form :

https://academia.stackexchange.com/contact